# clone() the initial element after is removed

Tags: jquery

I have some trouble with this for a couple of hours and didn't manage to find a solution, although i understand the cause of problem.

I clone elements one by one and i remove them from body from top when the scroll bar apears. The elements have a mousedown event to change the color from red to black or silver depending on the number generated by Math.random().

My problem is when the first element is removed(the initial one with color red) , the clone() is cloning the next one with the color changed. I want to clone only the initial square.

This phenomen happens because I used method `.first()` to tell machine what element i want to clone. If i remove `.first()`, the clone() method will create multiple elements instead of one per time but also this cause the problem to create the changed color element.

http://jsfiddle.net/cy3e5nro/

here's the code:

```
var running = false
$(document).click(function(){
    if(running){
        return;
    }
    running = true;
var endless = setInterval(function(){

var random = Math.floor(2 * Math.random());
var math = (random == 1)? 0 : 1;

$(".square").first().clone().addClass('number'+math).fadeIn().appendTo('#container').on('mousedown',function(){
    if(math<1){
        $(this).css('background-color','black').unbind('mousedown');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-color','silver').unbind('mousedown')
    }});
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:'+=70'},1000,'linear')},1000);

$(window).on('scroll',function(){
if($(".square:first").offset().top + $(".square:first").height() < $(window).scrollTop()){
    $(".square:first").remove()}
});
})
```

Help please.

Comment: The markup is also important. You can put a full runnable example in the question using Stack Snippes; no need for jsFiddle anymore.

Comment: I forgot about that, I update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This phenomen happens because I used method .first() to tell machine what element i want to clone.

It sounds like you want to remember that for future cloning, so up next to your `running`variable, add a:

```
var square;
```

and then change this:

```
$(".square").first().clone().addClass(...
```

to

```
if (!square) {
    square = $(".square").first();
}
square.clone().addClass(...
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy3e5nro/1/)

Comment: This ask my question. Thank you sir.